# Dual Boot and Booting Issue

Tags: multi-boot, linux-mint, bootloader, boot-partition, bootrepair

I NEED help desperately.

Some time ago I dual booted my Satellite c55t-b5230 (windows 8.1 & Ubuntu 14.10). Everything worked awesome Grub menu was present for months until it disappeared. Due to that I said proly a fresh install will bring back grub menu. I attempted to install Mint 17.1 it only recognized Linux and not windows so installed thinking that mint would just install on the Ubuntu partition.  After successful installation I rebooted.  That is where I was presented with the dreaded message "Reboot and select proper boot device or insert proper boot media in drive and press a key"  what is happening where did I go wrong?

Comment: The crux is in "thinking that mint would just install on the Ubuntu partition". It's essential to know your current partition table. Burn a live cd (I'd recommend gparted livecd) and do a `fdisk -l` on a command line.

Comment: Will o be able to recover my files

Comment: I looked at my hard drive via gParted and I didn't see a partition for Windows...

Comment: Obviously I'm a noobie I wanted to try linux

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what has happened, but try using a live CD and bootdiskrepair (search Google for more info) to help.